# Auto Calculation of machine run time between machine offline - Machine online with shift variables

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have these scenarios:

**Scenario 1**

- Machine offline 27/07/15 18:00
- Machine online 29/07/15 12:00

This machine runs for 3 shifts @ 8hrs per shift which will give us the resulting breakdown time of 42hrs.

This calculation can be resolved with the basic
datediff() function

However;

**Scenario 2**

- Machine offline 27/07/15 18:00
- Machine online 29/07/15 12:00

This machine runs only for 2 shifts @ 8hrs per shift so the resulting breakdown time for this would be 26 hrs.

1. How can I calculate this in my form though a VBA?
2. is it possible to have the VBA formula to accommodate for both scenarios?

Comment: From the timings you have provided, it looks to me like machine #1 runs 24 hours a day (Shift 1 00:00-08:00, Shift 2 08:00-16:00, Shift 3 16:00-24:00), and machine #2 only does the first two of these shifts, not working between 16:00 and 00:00. Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct, I have 82 machines in the factory, 1/4 of those run for 24 hrs and the rest run for 16 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you just want to calculate the shift duration and total run time?

```
Dim intShifts As Integer
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date
Dim dblShiftDuration As Double
Dim dblTtlRunTime As Double

If Me.SomeBooleanControl = True Then 'checkbox control on form etc
    intShifts = 3
Else
    intShifts = 2
End If

dblTtlRunTime = DateDiff("n", dteStart, dteEnd) / 60 'Run time in hours
dblShiftDuration = dblTtlRunTime / intShifts 'Shift duration in hours
```

Or is it the amount of time the machine was not being operated?

```
Dim intShifts As Integer
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date
Dim dblShiftDuration As Double
Dim dblDowntime As Double
Dim dblTtlRunTime As Double

dblShiftDuration = 8 'Shift duration in hours

'If Me.SomeBooleanControl = True Then 'checkbox control on form etc
'    intShifts = 3
'Else
'    intShifts = 2
'End If
intShifts=Me.Shifts

If Weekday(dteStart, vbMonday) > Weekday(dteEnd, vbMonday) Then 'this dangerously assumes it will not run longer than 6 days
    dblTtlRunTime = (DateDiff("n", dteStart, dteEnd) / 60) - 48 'Run time in hours, minus the weekend
Else
    dblTtlRunTime = DateDiff("n", dteStart, dteEnd) / 60 'Run time in hours
End If

dblDowntime = dblTtlRunTime - (intShifts * dblShiftDuration) 'downtime duration in hours
```

Comment: Basically the amount of time the machine is not operating, as per each breakdown.

Comment: Also which event would I need to write that second VBA? on update? In the form I also have a box that automatically updates as to whether the an asset runs for 2 or 3 shifts. That box is titled "Shifts". The final variable is to also dismiss Saturday and Sunday as machines do not operate on those days.

Comment: Most likely you will want to use the Current event, but a button event or control lost focus event will work well too. Depends how your Shifts control is being fed. Is it autocalculated via table def? Or is there some vba filling it out on an event?

Comment: I was thinking of using the later option by filling out VBA on an event.

Comment: Question though the "Me.SomeBooleanControl" is that a command? I know "Me." is

Comment: The Me.SomeBooleanControl is just a placeholder for whatever boolean returning control you may choose to use, for example a checkbox.

Me. just refers to the current instance of the form, it's not strictly necessary.

For example if you chose to use a checkbox it might be "Me.CheckBox1"

Comment: Since you have a control called "Shifts" that holds the number of shifts, and since you are using a VBA routine to populate that control, I suggest you run the VBA provided above immediately after you populate it (assuming of course the Start/End times are available). If the Start/End times are filled out AFTER the "Shifts" control is populated, you should use the update events of the Start/End controls to run the above code.

Comment: Make sure you have some validation code there as well! (IE: making sure the start value is less than the end value, making sure neither are null, making sure the Shifts control is populated, etc)

Comment: Thank you I will try this as soon as I get the time to, I have just been assigned different work so I have currently put this project aside. I will notify you as soon as I try it. Thank you for all your help thus far.